# Clarification request on packing-covering theorem.

Tags: graph-theory

Diestel's "Graph Theory" (5th edition) states the following theorem (and refers to it as the "packing-covering" theorem) by Bowler and Carmesin (2015):

> For every connected multigraph $G = (V, E)$ and every $k \in \mathbb{N}$ there is a  partition $P$ of $V$ such that every $G[U]$ with $U \in P$ has $k$ edge-disjoint
> spanning trees and the edges of $G/P$ can be covered by $k$ spanning trees.

I'm confused how it can work for any such $k$. Take the graph $G$ that consists of just a single vertex. It is connected and there is only one possible partition $P$. With $G = U \in P$. So, if $k$ is, say, 50 (or more) this should not be possible as there is only possible spanning tree, much less 50 edge-disjoint spanning trees.

Is it suppose to be that $G$ is also $k$-edge connected? I am still in the process of understanding the given proof, however, it does not seems to utilize that $G$ is $k$-edge connected, so I have doubts $k$-edge connectivity is what is being required as well. Any help understanding $k$ would be appreciated. For instance how can I interpret the theorem above for $G$ with $V(G) = \{a\}$ (like above)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the spanning trees are required to be edge-disjoint but not necessarily vertex-disjoint. In your case, you can just take the spanning tree consisting of the single vertex $50$ times.

$k$-edge-connectivity does not play a role here. For example, let $G = C$ be a cycle and $k=2$. Now $G$ is $2$-edge-connected, but the only induced subgraphs that contain two edge-disjoint spanning trees are the singletons. On the other hand, you can cover $C$ with two spanning trees. So in this case $P$ partitions the vertices into singletons. Similarly, if $G$ is a forest and $k > 1$, then $P$ will consist of singletons.